# Apt-file cache files location

Tags: linux, apt, cache, apt-file

Where are the cache files of the `apt-file` program ? Looks like it has some large files because it contains the information about files within all the packages in the repository (installed or uninstalled).But I cannot find their location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt-file` stores its indexes alongside the other `apt` indexes, in `/var/lib/apt/lists` by default. Look for the files with “Contents” in their name.